# JavaFX: custom ScatterChart

Tags: javafx-8

I'm experimenting with custom javafx controls and I have some problems with ScatterChart.
What I would like to do is to extend the standard ScatterChart so that I can add a property that I would later bind to the viewport of an ImageView.
Before embarking in the binding thing (that is new to me as well) I tried a minimum implementation just to see if I got the things right. Here is the code of the custom BindableChart

```
public class BindableChart<X,Y> extends ScatterChart<X,Y>
    public BindableChart(@NamedArg("xAxis")Axis<X> xAxis,@NamedArg("yAxis")Axis<Y> yAxis){
        super(xAxis,yAxis);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
        getClass().getResource("/fxml/BindableChart.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

and here its fxml code

```
<fx:root ...>
    <xAxis>
        <NumberAxis ... />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <NumberAxis ... />
    </yAxis>
</fx:root>
```

When I try to run a test application that includes the BindableChart class I got a PropertyNotFoundException saying that the xAxis property does not exist or is read-only.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to define the axes twice: once in the FXML file and once in the Java code. Note that by the time you call `load()` on the FXML loader (i.e. by the time you parse the FXML file), the axes have already been defined via a call to the superclass constructor.

If you are going to subclass `ScatterChart` then you pretty much have to initialize the axes via Java code. If you want to force the axes to be instances of `NumberAxis`, then you can do so by creating them in the call to `super()`. Of course, `NumberAxis` is a subclass `Axis<Number>`, so this forces `BindableChart` to be a subclass of `ScatterChart<Number, Number>`, so you end up with

```
package bindablechart ;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;

public class BindableChart extends ScatterChart<Number, Number> {
    public BindableChart(){
        super(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                getClass().getResource("BindableChart.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

and the FXML becomes

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" type="bindablechart.BindableChart">

</fx:root>
```

(At this point, the FXML may become completely redundant; I don't know what else you have there, if anything.)

A test for this version looks like:

```
package bindablechart;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BindableChartTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BindableChart());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Or you can include it in another FXML file simply with

```xml
<BindingChart />
```

---

If you want to let the user of this class specify the axes, you can do so, but you still remove them from the FXML (since the user is specifying them...):

```
package bindablechart;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;

public class BindableChart<X,Y> extends ScatterChart<X, Y> {
    public BindableChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") Axis<X> xAxis, @NamedArg("yAxis") Axis<Y> yAxis){
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                getClass().getResource("BindableChart.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

with the same FXML file as above.

In this case the test case looks like

```
package bindablechart;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BindableChartTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(
            new BindableChart<Number, Number>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis()));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

or you can create one in FXML with

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import bindablechart.BindableChart?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <BindableChart>
        <xAxis><NumberAxis/></xAxis>
        <yAxis><NumberAxis/></yAxis>
    </BindableChart>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see that I really rushed my study of the whole fxml part.

Comment: I was playing with the code and I still have some problems with xAxis and yAxis though. 
When I use Netbeans to create a FXML and try to customize the BindableChart (second strategy suggested by @James_D), the IDE correctly suggests me as possible field/variable xAxis  and yAxis. If I pick either of them, however, I get a message error saying that the class does not support those properties.

Comment: Probably your IDE and/or Scene Builder don't understand @NamedArg. It's a fairly new addition to the API and not well (I.e. at all) documented.